# I have error in folloing code of php for update

Tags: php, mysql

the below query is not working

```
$query= mysql_query('SELECT  * FROM Registration WHERE name="'.$_POST['Username'].'" & password="'.$_POST['Password']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `,` instead of `set` between each fields. Use this altered query,

```
('UPDATE Registration SET name="'.$_POST['Username'].'" , password="'.$_POST['Password'].'" , city="'.$_POST['City'].'" , state="'.$_POST['State'].'" , country="'.$_POST['Country'].'" WHERE id='.$_POST['user_id']);
```

Comment: This is still a syntax error, as well as being totally unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Use the word **SET** once only in your query. And separate each data by *comma*(**,**).

You should also consider escaping the string of your variables before using them into your query.

If you are using **MySQLi**, you can do this:

```
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['Username']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['Password']);
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['City']);
$state=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['State']);
$country=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['Country']);
$userid=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['user_id']);

$query="UPDATE Registration SET name='$username', password='$password', city='$city', state='$state', country='$country' WHERE id='$userid'";

mysqli_query($connection,$query); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
```

Comment: OP hasn't tagged it `mysqli`....

Comment: "might want to consider escaping" should be "absolutely must"